# How to find $(a,n)$ such that : $5^a+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {3\cdot 2^n-1}$ and $3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to find such integer pair $(a,n)$ that :

$\begin{cases}
 5^a+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {3\cdot 2^n-1} \\
  3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod a\\
 
\end{cases}$

where $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$

Comment: I still wonder every now and then why it was that you wanted to know this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example $n = 3$, $a = 11$.  Why did you want to know?

EDIT:  I guess that only answers the 'Is it possible?' part.  As for how to find $(a,n)$, well actually I used my computer, but $(11,3)$ is the smallest pair that could possibly work, so it would have made sense to check it first.  So far my computer has only found one other pair: $(191,7)$.  My code probably isn't very good, though.

UPDATE:  Also $(3071,11)$.  Note that $191 = 3\cdot2^6 - 1$ and $3071 = 3\cdot2^{10} - 1$, but it is not the case that the pair $(3\cdot 2^{n-1} - 1, n)$ works for every $n\equiv 3 \mod 4$.  This fails already for $n = 15$.